# eslint [vue/no-unused-vars] error in vue template

Tags: html, vue.js, eslint

Maybe this will be useful to somebody.

i have vue template with html in it

```
<template slot="HEAD_Status" slot-scope="data">
    <!-- some html without using of data -->
</template>
```

And Eslint generate [vue/no-unused-vars] 'data' is defined but never used.

I tried to use eslint-disable-line without any success (looks like because it's in vue file) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i edit my template:

```
<template slot="HEAD_Status" slot-scope="{}"></template>
```

e.g. replace data to {} in slot-scope.

Looks like another solution, we can move html from vue template to html file:

```
<template src="./someTemaplte.html></template>
```

And in someTemaplte.html insert our html:

```
<template slot="HEAD_Status" slot-scope="data"></template>
```

P.S. i didn't try the solution with a move to html file.